# Aggregate function returning different result compared to the algebraic expression of rows

Tags: sql

I´ve recently started with SQL and would like to know the following:

I have a problem I´m trying to solve, and both my solution and the official resolution are very similar, yet return very different results, the problem consists of a table with the following values

[image: Table]:

I am supposed to "find the total domestic and international sales that can be attributed to each director"

Here is what I wrote :

```
SELECT Director,(Domestic_sales + International_sales) AS Total_sales From Movies
INNER JOIN Boxoffice
    ON Movies.Id=Boxoffice.Movie_Id
GROUP BY Director
```

[image: My results]

And here is the official solution:

```
SELECT director, SUM(domestic_sales + international_sales) as Cumulative_sales_from_all_movies
FROM movies
    INNER JOIN boxoffice
        ON movies.id = boxoffice.movie_id
GROUP BY director;
```

[image: Official result]

I understand that the SUM aggregated function will do the trick, but why does simply adding up the values as I did return a different value? Issit because it's not taking into consideration the different films, but just adding up one of the lists in the movie and throwing that result?

I´ve looked elsewhere and also checked other questions seeing if I could answer this, but to no avail.

Thanks everyone and have a great week!

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: The first query is invalid standard SQL and every self-respecting database should reject that. Which DBMS product are you using? [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: @geasa . . . What don't you understand?  The difference between the queries is obvious (hint:  `SUM()`).

Comment: I am assuming you're using MySQL because it is allowing you to do studpid group by. You just need to wrap the addition inside `SUM` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why does simply adding up the values as I did return a different value? Issit because it's not taking into consideration the different films, but just adding up one of the lists in the movie and throwing that result?

Your query is not standard SQL.  In fact, this will return an error in almost all databases, including the most recent versions of MySQL, because you are aggregating by one column but have other non-aggregated columns in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT m.Director, (bo.Domestic_sales + bo.International_sales) AS Total_sales 
FROM Movies m JOIN
     Boxoffice bo
     ON M.Id = bo.Movie_Id
GROUP BY m.Director;
```

(I added table aliases, which are highly recommended.)

In *older* versions of MySQL, this returns an *arbitrary* value for the sum -- from one matching row.  The equivalent in more recent versions uses `ANY_VALUE()`:

```
SELECT m.Director, ANY_VALUE(bo.Domestic_sales + bo.International_sales) AS Total_sales 
FROM Movies m JOIN
     Boxoffice bo
     ON M.Id = bo.Movie_Id
GROUP BY m.Director;
```

Obviously, an arbitrary value is different from a `SUM()`.

I would advise you to set the session to avoid this problem.  You can set [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) to get the standard and compatible behavior.

Comment: Thank you Gordon! I did not know about Aliases and just learned 2 new things from your answer! I will make sure to start using them from now on (as they actually seem very useful).